# Using UIAlertViewStyleTextInput to add test to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to add items to an `NSMutableArray` based on user input.  I've already taken care of the switch for handling different places for the user to enter information (I did it using a `UIAlertView` to capture the text input of the user).  Reading through this I know that it is only resetting the array every time. I enter something new and is only saving the last one, but I've tried a few different formats and can't seem to get it to add to the array vs. overwriting what's already been stored in it.  *Here is the statement that handles adding the objects*

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
_tankFilterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_tankMovementArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_tankLightsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *newLightsString = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *newFiltrationString = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *newMovementString = [[NSString alloc] init];

switch (alertView.tag)
{
    case 0:
            newLightsString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
            NSLog(@"New Lighting Added: %@", newLightsString);
            [_tankLightsArray addObject:newLightsString];
            NSLog(@"Number of Lights Added: %lu", _tankLightsArray.count);
        //            [_tankLights reloadData];
        break;
    case 1:
        newFiltrationString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        [_tankFilterArray addObject:newFiltrationString];
        NSLog(@"Number of Filtration Parts Added: %lu", _tankFilterArray.count);
        NSLog(@"New Filtration Added: %@", newFiltrationString);
        //            [_tankFiltration reloadData];
        break;
    case 2:
        newMovementString = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
        [_tankMovementArray addObject:newMovementString];
        NSLog(@"Number of Filtration Parts Added: %lu", _tankMovementArray.count);
        NSLog(@"New Movement Added: %@", newMovementString);
        //            [_tankMovement reloadData];
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

And where it's declared in the header file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tankLightsArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tankFilterArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tankMovementArray;
```

*EDITED for clarity*

Comment: Show the definition of `_tankLightsArray` and other lines of code where it is used / replaced - where are these lines of code?

Comment: _tankLightsArray is a mutable array declared in the header file and allocated before the switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whenever you are clicking the button its reinitializing the Array. Try to initialize it somewhere else.

Comment: Nope, still returning 1 each time it's run

Comment: I think whenever you are clicking the button its reinitializing the Array. Try to initialize it somewhere else. May be in `ViewdidLoad`.